# Improper Integral with supremum

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, real-numbers

I tried to calculate the following:
$$
\int_0^{1/2}\displaystyle\left[\sup_{y\neq x, \ y\in[0, 1/2]}\dfrac{1}{y-x}\int_x^yt^{-1}\ln^{-2}{t}dt\right](-x\ln{x})dx
$$
and obtained $\dfrac{\pi^2-6}{12\ln{2}}$. Below the calculations:
$$
\sup_{y\neq x, \ y\in[0, 1/2]}\dfrac{1}{y-x}\int_x^yt^{-1}\ln^{-2}{t}dt=\sup_{y\neq x, \ y\in[0, 1/2]}\dfrac{\ln{y}-\ln{x}}{(y-x)\ln{x}\ln{y}}=2\dfrac{\ln{x}+\ln{2}}{(1-2x)\ln{x}\ln{2}}
$$
Thus
$$
\dfrac{2}{\ln{2}}\int_0^{1/2}\dfrac{\ln{x}+\ln{2}}{(1-2x)\ln{x}}
(-x\ln{x})dx=-\dfrac{2}{\ln{2}}\int_0^{1/2}\dfrac{\ln{x}+\ln{2}}{(1-2x)}xdx=-\dfrac{2}{\ln{2}}\dfrac{6-\pi^2}{24}=\dfrac{\pi^2-6}{12\ln{2}}
$$
I suppose there's something wrong.

Comment: Would you provide your work?

Comment: I've just edited the question, thanks.